Evaluating $\int_0^a \frac{\cos ^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x^2} \ dx$
Could someone help me in evaluating this integral? $a$ is assumed to be real.
I tried different things but not getting anywhere. Thank you.
$$\int_0^a \frac{\cos ^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x^2} \ dx$$

Please write down your attempt and where you are stuck at.

I apologize for not informing about my background research. Actually I think that I am able to prove that the integral is divergent, I will post an answer myself.

The integral can be shown to be divergent as follows.
The indefinite integral can be shown to be:
$$\text{indef} = \frac{-\sqrt{\pi } x C\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi } x}\right)-2}{4 x}$$
Here $C(x)$ is the Fresnel C function.
Except at $0$, the integrand and the integral do not have any singularity in the range $[0, \infty]$ - this can be verified from the plots below.
Plot of the integrand:

Plot of the indefinite integral:

Assuming $eps$ to be a small number greater than $0$, the following definite integral can be determined from the indefinite integral:
$$\text{def} = \int_{\text{eps}}^1 \frac{\cos ^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x^2} \, dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{4} \left(-2-\sqrt{\pi } C\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)\right)-\frac{-2-\text{eps} \sqrt{\pi }
   C\left(\frac{2}{\text{eps} \sqrt{\pi }}\right)}{4 \text{eps}}$$
This limit can be shown to be infinity, thus proving the divergence.
$$\underset{\text{eps}\to 0}{\text{lim}}\text{def} = \infty$$
